# STTwitter: メソッドを呼び出すと引数がいつの間にかnilになる

Tags: objective-c

以下のコードの**BlockHelpers#block:successBlock**:を呼び出し、そのメソッドの中で**STTwitterAPI#postBlocksCreateWithScreenName**:....に渡した引数(userId)が、いつの間にかnilになってしまい、結果的に ** [__NSCFNumber st_urlEncodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ** といったエラーが出てきます(__NSCFNumberがどこから出てきたかはよくわかりません)

BlockHelpers.m

```
+(void)block:(NSString *)userId successBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))blk{
  LogSuc(@"uid::: %@", userId);　// まだnilになってない
  [[Helpers getAPIfromCache] postBlocksCreateWithScreenName:nil
                                               orUserID:userId
                                        includeEntities:nil
                                             skipStatus:nil
                                           successBlock:^(NSDictionary *user){
                                             blk(user);
                                           }errorBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                             LogErr(@"BlockHelpers: block: %@", error);
                                           }];
}
```

Helpers#getAPIfromCacheはSTTwitterAPIのインスタンスを返すメソッドです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問にあるメソッドを呼び出している側で`userId`に`NSNumber`を渡しているのでは。
`[userId class]`か`[userId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`をログ出力すれば検証できます。

Comment: (返信遅れてすみません) おっしゃる通りuserIdがNSNumberになっていたようです。ありがとうございました!